# Using awk to find value, skip blanks

Tags: awk

I am using awk to get a username in a huge log file, which contains multiple lines with the same value. I've figured out how to just pull that last entry, but sometimes the result is blank. I'd like to skip a blank value and move on to the next one.  Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pulls last logged in user from GPS.log
GPuser=$(grep 'Actual user for gateway login is' /Library/Logs/PaloAltoNetworks/GlobalProtect/PanGPS.log | awk '{user=$13}END{print user}')

echo "Username is $GPuser"

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since there is no sample input this in untested

```
awk '/Actual user for gateway login is/ && $13!="" {user=$13} 
     END {print "Username is", user}' logfile
```

there is no need for `grep` or `echo`